# Can't add anything to startup and default apps

Tags: windows-8.1, boot

I'm using Windows 8.1.

Whenever I click a torrent file it asks for the default app, in the list there isn't any of my torrent apps. When I manually select BitTorrent.exe, It doesn't open it and It doesn't have any changes. Also just saw that my antivirus (ESET) didn't boot either. Also chromium asks me to make it my default browser but when I click "Set as default" it that menu, there isn't chromium. Please help.

I don't know what caused this. I did 2 things that could cause this:
1- I used Advanced SystemCare 7 Pro's full check and I fixed all.
2- I checked an entry of magnet link on registry (I haven't edited it) and edited chromium's Local State (in C:\Users\Arda\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Local State)

I have a System Restore Point but I'll Restore only if it is the only choice.

Comment: Have you verified the version of ESET your using is capatible with Windows 8,1?

Comment: At the end of the day you remove vital information your register. This is the percise reason Windows does not have a built-in utility to "clean" your register.  Its not required and despite the snake oil that is normally sold it does not make your system faster.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, Its capatible and please send your second comment as an answer, I'll uprate it and make it the answer. thanks

Comment: My second comment isn't an answer to your question though.